# What does the red arrow pointing up and right mean in the Package Explorer in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am using SpringSource Tool Suite (essentially Eclipse Helios ++) and I just started using Subversive.  I've been using all of the tools except Subversive for quite a while and I've never seen these red arrow icons before (or are these called "adornments"?), so I suspect Subversive is the source, but I can't find anything on line that says what they mean.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup those are Subversive's decorations ( the arrow is for "switched")

http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/svn_label_decor.php

Comment: That's consistent with what I did, but under when does it get 'cleared'?